# Grab MySQL info over php with vb.net

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

i need small help since im stuck, and im not that good with php and vB.net connections...
So here is the problem, i manage to get connected to db and php script shows me if im connected or not, grab if user/pw is correct everything works fine, but now i do not know how to grab, on new form show up, data from that user and display it in label, like in db it has date of registration, last login and email, i want to get them on my second form.. so if anyone could help me out to sort those things and manage to complete goal, i would be really thankfull!

Usercheck.php

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $connect = mysql_pconnect("localhost","username","password");
        if($connect)
        {
            $select = mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$connect);
            if($select)
            {
                $user = mysql_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
                $pwd = mysql_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
                $GetRows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTableHere WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pwd'");
                $RowCount=mysql_num_rows($GetRows);
                if($RowCount>0)
                {
                    die("Correct !");
                }
                else
                {
                    die("Incorrect !");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                die("Unable to select database." . mysql_error());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die("Unable connect to database." . mysql_error());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die("Access Denied!");
    }
}
else
{
    die("Access Denied!");
}
?>
```

Snippet from Form1.vb

```
Function AuthUser(ByVal AuthenticationPage As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim Data As String = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Username), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Password))
        Dim ResponseBytes() As Byte = wc.UploadData(AuthenticationPage, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data))
        Dim Response As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResponseBytes)
        If Response.Contains("Correct") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If AuthUser("http://127.0.0.1/Usercheck.php", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) Then
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("You have provided invalid username or password. Unable to login.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/vb-net/bridging-the-gap-talking-to-mysql-from-vb-net-through-php-and-xml/

It shows how display data from mysql via xml generated by php.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a value as a global variable in vb.net. You can then access said variable all over project, or even in another form.